# How to transfer issues from bitbucket to Trac?

Tags: python, bitbucket, trac

I wish to transfer all the bugs reported on Bitbucket (Issues) to Trac. I've no knowledge to use python and eggs.

Can some one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely be out of luck regarding a ready-made solution.

Anyway, once you hire someone or dig into Python yourself this seems like a doable task. Here are the bits that I would start from:

- Bitbucket issue [import/export format is well documented](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=330796872).
- Get further inspiration from a [Python script](https://bitbucket.org/theasci/redmine-issues-to-bitbucket/overview), that has been made to import (Redmine) issue into Bitbucket - so it's mostly the other way-round on the Bitbucket side.
- For the Trac side you could borrow ideas and code from [TicketImportPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TicketImportPlugin).